# Search data who doesn´t appear between values

Tags: php, mysql

here is my problem,

Imagine this table

```
id| idcompany
----------
1 | 1
----------
2 | 2
----------
3 | 1
----------
5 | 1
----------
6 | 2
```

I did a code in PHP like this:

```
if id <= 2 then DAY1
if id BETWEEN 3,4 then DAY2
if id BETWEEN 5,6 then DAY3
```

Looking to the table we can assume that company 1 appears on Day1, Day2 and Day 3
and company 2 appears Day1 and Day3

What I want to accomplish here is: How can I SELECT in SQL all the companies
who won't participate on Day 2?

I already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE id NOT BETWEEN 3 AND 4
GROUP BY(idcompany)
```

But its obvious that wont work because  the Query will select the idcompany from another days and print on result.

Can someone help me to fig this out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by **and company 3 appears Day1 and Day3** I don't see any `company 3` in datatable you provide

Comment: You are absolutely right! It supposed to be Company 2. Sry about this.

Comment: Why do you finally choose wrong answer?

Comment: Im new on this, The right answer are both from McAdam and Alex. Sry about this.

Comment: I don't see how McAdam answer match to your needs. But that is your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, I got you correctly

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f9921/1

```
SELECT idcompany
FROM tickets
GROUP BY idcompany
HAVING SUM(IF(id IN (3,4),1,0))=0
```

**UPDATE** If you need an interval you can replace condition in `SUM`:

```
SELECT idcompany
FROM tickets
GROUP BY idcompany
HAVING SUM(IF(id BETWEEN 330601 AND 40800,1,0))=0
```

Comment: How can I implement that using the interval 30601 to 40800? I cant understand your code but using sqlfiddle I can see that works!

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of companies who didn't participate on day two, start by getting a list of those who did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT companyID
FROM myTable
WHERE id BETWEEN 3 AND 4;
```

Then you can exclude them from the final result by selecting all companies, and using a `NOT IN` operator to filter those out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT companyID
FROM myTable
WHERE companyId NOT IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT companyID
  FROM myTable
  WHERE id BETWEEN 3 AND 4);
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf977a/4) example.

Comment: Thanks so much my friend. I worked like a charm. Now I can proceed with my code!

Comment: @J.Moura not a problem! If this is the solution you use to solve your problem, accepting the answer will help other users understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your table is rather confusing, I can't seem to find the information where Company 1 appears on Day 2.

But if I have understood correctly, here is a simple **NOT** or **!=** operand for the **WHERE** operator example:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets
WHERE id != 3 AND id != 4
```

Comment: Thanks to your help but it wont fix the problem. I have to filter about 51000 tickets :)

Comment: Glad I could help, however next time provide more reliable data when asking a question. Also I would appreciate an up-vote :)